# Unable to Capture File Path

Tags: c#, xaml

With the code below, I split the files after "/" and upload them to a list. But in this shredding process, I also need to write the actual path of the file in the filepath field. What should I do?

For example;

```
/dowload/b/a
Loop-1;SubItem = new Treeview()
{
    name = download
    Level = 2,
    **filepath = /download/b/a,
    SubItems = new List<Treeview>()
};

Loop-2;subItem = new Treeview()
{
    name = b,
    Level = 2,
    **filepath = /download/b/a,
    **SubItems = new List<Treeview>()
};
```

Must be;

```
Loop-1;subItem = new Treeview()
{
    name = download Level = 2,
    **filepath = /download,
    **SubItems = new List<Treeview>()
};

Loop-2;subItem = new Treeview()
{
    name = b,
    Level = 2,
    **filepath = /download/b,
    **SubItems = new List<Treeview>()
};
```

```
private void FilePath(System.Windows.Controls.TreeView treeView, IEnumerable<string> paths, char pathSeparator)
{
    List<Treeview> sourceCollection = new List<Treeview>();
    foreach (string path in paths)
    {
        string[] fileItems = path.Split(pathSeparator);
        if (fileItems.Any())
        {
            Treeview root = sourceCollection.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name.Equals(fileItems[0]) && x.Level.Equals(1));
            if (root == null)
            {
                root = new Treeview()
                {
                    Level = 1,
                    Name = fileItems[0],
                    filepath = path,
                    SubItems = new List<Treeview>()
                };
                sourceCollection.Add(root);
            } // if

            if (fileItems.Length > 1)
            {
                Treeview parentItem = root;
                int level = 2;
                for (int i = 1; i < fileItems.Length; ++i)
                {
                    Treeview subItem = parentItem.SubItems.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name.Equals(fileItems[i]) && x.Level.Equals(level));
                    if (subItem == null)
                    {   
                        subItem = new Treeview()
                        {
                            Name = fileItems[i],
                            Level = level,
                            filepath = path,
                            SubItems = new List<Treeview>
                        };
                              parentItem.SubItems.Add(subItem);
                    } // if

                    parentItem = subItem;
                    level++;
                } // for
            } // if
        } // if
    } // foreach
    TreeView.ItemsSource = sourceCollection;
} // void
```

Comment: Where do you get the `paths` collection/array from? Do you do something like `Directory.GetFiles` to get the list of file path strings?

Comment: yes. I'm reading the .iso content with Discutils and breaking it down for treeview here.

Comment: Alright. One more question about the Level property in your TreeView nodes. What do you intend to use the Level values for, are they really required?

Comment: Since the file paths are line by line, I thought I needed to number them. That's why I used also my project does not support TreeView node. xaml. I have to use it as treeviewitem.

Comment: "_Since the file paths are line by line, I thought I needed to number them_" Wait, let me try to understand this: you essentially do not need the level number for whatever purpose your app should fullfil. It's just that you are unsure how to correctly render/present the items in the tree correctly. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Yes that's true.

Comment: Alright. Then i suggest a two step approach with two main focuses which you should tackle independently. First, write a method that only creates the hierarchical tree data using some custom class/record type that represent the nodes in the file/directory tree. Just do that first. Don't look at, don't think about XAML or your UI. However, already think about what information the nodes need to hold for display/presentation and for further functions/features of your program.

Comment: All these individual bits of information in the nodes needs to be accessible through properties (because data binding with the respective GUI elements or templates). As a quick shot from the hip i would roughly think of something like that: `public record FileSystemEntryNode(string FullPath, string Name, bool IsFile, IReadOnlyList<FileSystemEntryNode>? SubItems, FileSystemEntryNode? ParentNode);`

Comment: As far as i can see, DiscUtils has methods that provides the list of subdirectories as well as files in a directory. Creating a method that accept a directory path which then gets the sub dirs and files for this directory path from DiscUtils. Build the FileSystemEntryNode node representing the directory path. For each sub directory, call this method recursively, thus letting it build and return the node for each sub directory. Add the nodes returned by the recursive of that method to the sub item list of the node that has been created for the directory path passed into the method.

Comment: Finally, after all that recursion into sub directories, create FileSystemEntryNode nodes for each of the files in the directory and add them to the list of sub items as well. If done correctly, you got a proper hierachical representation of the dir and file structure.

Comment: Again, do this first, and do this right. It make take some time, especially if you are unexperienced with recursion. Don't even bother with or get distracted by the UI stuff yet. To verify if you have build the the hierarchy correctly, write code that dumps the tree structure formed by the FileSystemEntryNodes into a text file. A Json serializer like System.Text.Json will come in handy for this purpose, as it pretty much does all this automatically. It is paramount that you verify that your code builds this FileSystemEntryNode hierarchy correctly.

Comment: Otherwise you will just get confused and overwhelmed when you start dealing with the UI stuff, because if you have significant bugs in your code creating the hierarchical data structure and then also bugs in your UI related code and templates, it can quickly become a hot mess that might be difficult to sort out and fix...

Comment: I really don't know if I can do this. Maybe you want to help me. I don't know if I can use both FileSystemEntryNode at the same time because I read virtual machine contents with Discutils. What you say is very difficult for me.

Comment: You have to do it. It's an incremental process. If recursion is a mystery to you, seek some tutorials that teach the concepts of recursion. "_I don't know if I can use both FileSystemEntryNode at the same time because I read virtual machine contents with Discutils._" I don't know what you try to say. Your code will create FileSystemEntryNode instances with information it gets from DiscUtils. These FileSystemEntryNode instances later will be bound to the UI. FileSystemEntryNode is just a class we... i... defined that represents a node (a directory or a file) in the directory tree structure.

Comment: Nodes are not working in my project because Wpf

Comment: "_Nodes are not working in my project because Wpf_" I don't know how to read this. Stop worrying about the UI stuff now. As i already said, The FileSystemEntryNode instances (specifically their properties containing information to be displayed) will be bound to the respective UI elements. If "nodes" are not working in your project, it's _not_ because of WPF. But again, don't worry about UI stuff _now_. Concentrate on properly creating the directory/file hierarchy as a data structure first. Make it easy for yourself, and try solving individual problems one after another, and not all at once.

Comment: If I send a TeamViewer link to your e-mail address, can you connect? Can you show me?

Comment: No. My apologies, but i don't do these things outside of Stackoverflow.com.

Comment: This made me sad :(